# 4 sql's, need to get each row from each sql where it has the same garage, tried nested loops but just multiplies responses

Tags: sql, vb.net, bootstrap-4

I am working on a page for work and stumped..
I have 4 tables that I need to get a count of each and display them within an element/box based on the  common garage number. Created sql for each table because need counts

Tried for each statement but repeats inners statements over and over again, because 21 garages

Using Visual Basic
Page using bootstrap

*** work added

Originally had all the for each statement nest within each other

```
Public Shared Function GetStations(ByVal section As String) As String
    'Dim sql As String = "SELECT WOEQ14 AS STATION, COUNT(WONUM) AS TOTAL FROM MAXIMO.WORKORDER WHERE (WOEQ13 LIKE '$RESP1$%' OR WOEQ13 LIKE '$RESP2$%' OR WOEQ13 LIKE '$RESP3$%') AND (CREWID = 'SSO' OR CREWID = 'PST') AND (HISTORYFLAG = 0) AND (ISTASK = 0) AND (WOEQ14 LIKE '$LOC1$' OR WOEQ14 LIKE '$LOC2$' OR WOEQ14 LIKE '$LOC3$') GROUP BY  ORDER BY STATION"
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT GARAGE, count(VEHICLE) as 'TOTAL' FROM MKTBLVEHINV WHERE (GARAGE LIKE '$GAR1$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR2$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR3$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR4$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR5$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR6$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR7$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR8$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR9$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR10$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR11$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR12$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR13$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR14$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR15$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR16$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR17$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR18$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR19$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR20$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR21$%') GROUP BY GARAGE ORDER BY GARAGE"
    Dim SQL2 As String = "SELECT HOME_GARAGE AS 'GARAGE', COUNT(VEHICLE_ID) AS 'OOS' FROM MKTBLOUTSER WHERE (HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR1$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR2$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR3$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR4$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR5$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR6$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR7$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR8$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR9$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR10$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR11$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR12$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR13$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR14$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR15$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR16$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR17$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR18$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR19$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR20$%' OR HOME_GARAGE LIKE '$GAR21$%') GROUP BY HOME_GARAGE ORDER BY HOME_GARAGE"
    Dim SQL3 As String = "SELECT GARAGE, COUNT(VEHICLE) AS 'RECALLS' FROM MKTBLRECALL WHERE (GARAGE LIKE '$GAR1$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR2$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR3$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR4$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR5$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR6$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR7$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR8$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR9$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR10$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR11$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR12$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR13$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR14$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR15$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR16$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR17$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR18$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR19$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR20$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR21$%') AND RECALL_STATUS IN ('REPORTED','DEFERRED','RAISED','JOBRAISED','JOB RAISED') AND ARCHIVE_STATUS = 'N' GROUP BY GARAGE ORDER BY GARAGE"
    Dim SQL4 As String = "SELECT GARAGE, COUNT(INSPECTION_TYPE) AS 'PM & Inspections' FROM MKTBLPMINSP WHERE (GARAGE LIKE '$GAR1$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR2$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR3$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR4$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR5$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR6$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR7$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR8$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR9$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR10$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR11$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR12$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR13$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR14$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR15$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR16$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR17$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR18$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR19$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR20$%' OR GARAGE LIKE '$GAR21$%') AND INSPECTION_STATUS = 'overdue' GROUP BY GARAGE ORDER BY GARAGE"

    Dim gar1 As String = ""
    Dim gar2 As String = ""
    Dim gar3 As String = ""
    Dim gar4 As String = ""
    Dim gar5 As String = ""
    Dim gar6 As String = ""
    Dim gar7 As String = ""
    Dim gar8 As String = ""
    Dim gar9 As String = ""
    Dim gar10 As String = ""
    Dim gar11 As String = ""
    Dim gar12 As String = ""
    Dim gar13 As String = ""
    Dim gar14 As String = ""
    Dim gar15 As String = ""
    Dim gar16 As String = ""
    Dim gar17 As String = ""
    Dim gar18 As String = ""
    Dim gar19 As String = ""
    Dim gar20 As String = ""
    Dim gar21 As String = ""
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = ArtCode.InitConn()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT gar1, gar2, gar3, gar4, gar5, gar6, gar7, gar8, gar9, gar10, gar11, gar12, gar13, gar14, gar15, gar16, gar17, gar18, gar19, gar20, gar21 FROM Sections WHERE section = '" & section & "'"
    Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            gar1 = dr("gar1").ToString()
            gar2 = dr("gar2").ToString()
            gar3 = dr("gar3").ToString()
            gar4 = dr("gar4").ToString()
            gar5 = dr("gar5").ToString()
            gar6 = dr("gar6").ToString()
            gar7 = dr("gar7").ToString()
            gar8 = dr("gar8").ToString()
            gar9 = dr("gar9").ToString()
            gar10 = dr("gar10").ToString()
            gar11 = dr("gar11").ToString()
            gar12 = dr("gar12").ToString()
            gar13 = dr("gar13").ToString()
            gar14 = dr("gar14").ToString()
            gar15 = dr("gar15").ToString()
            gar16 = dr("gar16").ToString()
            gar17 = dr("gar17").ToString()
            gar18 = dr("gar18").ToString()
            gar19 = dr("gar19").ToString()
            gar20 = dr("gar20").ToString()
            gar21 = dr("gar21").ToString()
        End If
    End Using

    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR1$", gar1)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR2$", gar2)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR3$", gar3)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR4$", gar4)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR5$", gar5)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR6$", gar6)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR7$", gar7)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR8$", gar8)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR9$", gar9)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR10$", gar10)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR11$", gar11)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR12$", gar12)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR13$", gar13)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR14$", gar14)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR15$", gar15)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR16$", gar16)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR17$", gar17)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR18$", gar18)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR19$", gar19)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR20$", gar20)
    SQL = SQL.Replace("$GAR21$", gar21)


    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR1$", gar1)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR2$", gar2)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR3$", gar3)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR4$", gar4)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR5$", gar5)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR6$", gar6)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR7$", gar7)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR8$", gar8)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR9$", gar9)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR10$", gar10)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR11$", gar11)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR12$", gar12)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR13$", gar13)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR14$", gar14)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR15$", gar15)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR16$", gar16)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR17$", gar17)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR18$", gar18)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR19$", gar19)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR20$", gar20)
    SQL2 = SQL2.Replace("$GAR21$", gar21)

    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR1$", gar1)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR2$", gar2)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR3$", gar3)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR4$", gar4)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR5$", gar5)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR6$", gar6)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR7$", gar7)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR8$", gar8)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR9$", gar9)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR10$", gar10)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR11$", gar11)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR12$", gar12)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR13$", gar13)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR14$", gar14)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR15$", gar15)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR16$", gar16)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR17$", gar17)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR18$", gar18)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR19$", gar19)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR20$", gar20)
    SQL3 = SQL3.Replace("$GAR21$", gar21)

    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR1$", gar1)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR2$", gar2)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR3$", gar3)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR4$", gar4)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR5$", gar5)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR6$", gar6)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR7$", gar7)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR8$", gar8)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR9$", gar9)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR10$", gar10)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR11$", gar11)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR12$", gar12)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR13$", gar13)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR14$", gar14)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR15$", gar15)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR16$", gar16)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR17$", gar17)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR18$", gar18)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR19$", gar19)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR20$", gar20)
    SQL4 = SQL4.Replace("$GAR21$", gar21)

    'get station list for this area
    'wrap it in bootstrap divs
    'station name should be hyperlink to report results (hijack)
    Dim result As String = " <div class=""row mb-3 mx-auto"">"

    Dim dt1 As System.Data.DataTable
    dt1 = ReportingClass.GetEplanDataTable(SQL)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt1.Rows
        result += "<div class=""col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-4 mb-2"">"
        result += "<div class=""card bg-gradient-forest border-dark shadow h-100"">"
        result += "<div class=""card-body m-2 text-white-800 text-center"">"
        result += "<br/>" + row(0).ToString
        result += "<a href='report.aspx?token=RUN|STATIONINFO|PARAMS&STATION=" + row(0).ToString + "' target=""_blank"" class=""rpt"">"
        result += "<br/>total vehicles= " + row(1).ToString + "</a>"
        result += "</div></div></div>"
    Next
    result += "</div>"


    result += " <div class=""row mb-3 mx-auto"">"
    Dim dt2 As System.Data.DataTable
    dt2 = ReportingClass.GetEplanDataTable(SQL2)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt2.Rows
        result += "<div class=""col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-4 mb-2"">"
        result += "<div class=""card bg-gradient-forest border-dark shadow h-100"">"
        result += "<div class=""card-body m-2 text-white-800 text-center"">"
        result += "<br/>" + row(0).ToString
        result += " <a href='report.aspx?token=RUN|STATIONINFO|PARAMS&STATION=" + row(0).ToString + "' target=""_blank"" class=""rpt"">"
        result += "<br/>OOS vehicles= " + row(1).ToString + "</a>"
        result += "</div></div></div>"
    Next
    result += "</div>"

    result += " <div class=""row mb-3 mx-auto"">"
    Dim dt3 As System.Data.DataTable
    dt3 = ReportingClass.GetEplanDataTable(SQL4)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt3.Rows
        result += "<div class=""col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-4 mb-2"">"
        result += "<div class=""card bg-gradient-forest border-dark shadow h-100"">"
        result += "<div class=""card-body m-2 text-white-800 text-center"">"
        result += "<br/>" + row(0).ToString
        result += " <a href='report.aspx?token=RUN|STATIONINFO|PARAMS&STATION=" + row(0).ToString + "' target=""_blank"" class=""rpt"">"
        result += "<br/>Recalls= " + row(1).ToString + "</a>"
        result += "</div></div></div>"
    Next
    result += "</div>"

    result += " <div class=""row mb-3 mx-auto"">"
    Dim dt4 As System.Data.DataTable
    dt4 = ReportingClass.GetEplanDataTable(SQL4)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt4.Rows
        result += "<div class=""col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-4 mb-2"">"
        result += "<div class=""card bg-gradient-forest border-dark shadow h-100"">"
        result += "<div class=""card-body m-2 text-white-800 text-center"">"
        result += "<br/>" + row(0).ToString
        result += " <a href='report.aspx?token=RUN|STATIONINFO|PARAMS&STATION=" + row(0).ToString + "' target=""_blank"" class=""rpt"">"
        result += "<br/>PM and Inspections= " + row(1).ToString + "</a>"
        result += "</div></div></div>"
    Next
    result += "</div>"


    Return result

End Function
```

Can anyone give me an ideas?

Comment: It's really unclear exactly what is going on here.  From what I can decipher the whole approch seems like a bit of a bodge for what looks like a pretty poor db design.  Can you maybe give us an example of your intended results and what you're getting at the moment.  Perhaps we might be able to put the finger on you problem.

Comment: I would also suggest, asking the exact same question twice with no obvious additional information when the first question has already been closed because of it not explaining the problem will get you no where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this gets you started.

```
"Select GARAGE, Count(VEHICLE) As TOTAL From MKTBLVEHINV Group By GARAGE;"

"SELECT HOME_GARAGE AS GARAGE, COUNT(VEHICLE_ID) AS 'OOS' FROM MKTBLOUTSER Group By GARAGE;"

"SELECT GARAGE, COUNT(VEHICLE) AS 'RECALLS' FROM MKTBLRECALL Group By GARAGE;"

"SELECT GARAGE, COUNT(INSPECTION_TYPE) AS 'PM & Inspections' FROM MKTBLPMINSP Group By Garage;"
```

If you need only certain garages, maybe the `Where GARAGE In`.... might help.